# Usage of Assalamu allikum and Jazak Allah Khair on the site

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please don't remove greetings like “ASSALAAMU ALAIKUM” from questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/please-dont-remove-greetings-like-assalaamu-alaikum-from-questions)

Asslamu allikum,

This was a comment from one of the associates of stack overflow for the usage of Islamic greetings.

The question on which we had the discussion : [What is the meaning and the usage of "Assalamu alaikum"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2146/337)

> At StackExchange, we generally discourage stock headers / greetings /
>   footers / signatures - by which I mean the "Asslamu allikum" / "Jazak
>   Allah Khair" on every post.

Let me know your views on this.

[Jazak Allah Khair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/337)

Comment: Small note: here on islam.SE, I am acting more as "experienced SE user" than "associate". While I do work for SE, I am not part of the community team. I'm moving the comment from the Q&A post to here, so it is available to all users:

Comment: A longer discussion [exists on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), but: *essentially* yes: it is noise. The actual question here is just the one-liner in the middle. It might make more sense to say thank you to someone who posts a good answer, *when they do so*. Which might also include: upvoting their answer. In terms of how this applies to islam.SE, that might make a sensible question for [meta.islam.SE](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/) - localy policy doesn't have to be *exactly* the same, after all.

Comment: sorry for that , will change it.re-read and let me know if you need any more changes.

Comment: it doesn't need a change; I was just clarifying my position here.

Comment: ok , then keeping it the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst is has great benefits of using such greetings, in a q&a forum it is best to keep it concise and specific :)