# Should the question on Mother vs. Husband, which happens to be unnecessarily long, be trimmed?

Tags: discussion, editing

The question [Mother Vs Husband](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11277/3487), is unnecessarily long and most of it's details are trivial and could be cleaned up without affecting the question and it's context.

Should this question be edited in order to just shorten it and remove things whose removal wont affect the question?

What should be the guideline on dealing with such questions?

Answer (score 1):

That's why there is an edit link under the question. Feel free to edit the question to clarify it as long as it doesn't change its meaning.