# How is question 35315 "Are all things that are not haram halal?" unclear?

Tags: discussion, moderation, specific-question, closed-questions

This post is about the question: [Are all things that are not haram halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35315/are-all-things-that-are-not-haram-halal)  It was recently put on hold by a diamond moderator:

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Bleeding Fingers♦ 12 hours ago

It was originally [closed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/35315/revisions) as a duplicate:

> Post Closed as "duplicate" by Rebecca J. Stones, Kilise, Medi1Saif, Sassir, nim of [Is something is not Halal, does that mean it's Haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7942/is-something-is-not-halal-does-that-mean-its-haram)  occurred Sep 12 '16 at 13:18

For me this question is completely clear.  What do you mean by selecting "unclear what you're asking"?

The body of the question is:

> If something is not haram, is it always halal? I'm wondering if there is some grey area in between.

Answer (score 2):

Questions on this platform are expected to be elaborate. We eschew
questions that are basically short/one-liners because they show lack of
research prior-asking.

A rudimentary [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=not%20haram%20means%20halal%3F) provides a link to a question on our
site as the first result. It was never explained as to why answers
there didn't satisfy the question. Therefore unclear.

For more: [How to improve tagging and question quality?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/940/3487) and [Take pride in your community, and work to build a site you can be proud of](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1157/3487)