# Don't append "SAWW", "PBUH", "RA", "AS" etc in front of names and titles if the original author hasn't and don't change it either

Tags: discussion, faq-content, editing

I have come across edits (plenty of examples out there) in which the author hadn't added any salutation in front of the name of the Prophet (saww), Ali (as) etc but somebody comes by and adds it.

**Do not do it.**

It's a matter of taste/believe/conviction/choice (call it *foobar*). If the author didn't intend to add any. You shouldn't either. (From the SO lens it's like changing the style/indentation of a piece of code. Which is discouraged AFAIK.)

It's not part of the [editing spirit](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/952/3487) and could be seen as reflecting/imposing one's *foobar* on that of the author. And might also be unwelcome to the author.

You're welcome and encouraged to make valuable post-improving edit. But don't make this part of your edit. **You're not mandated nor supposed to.**

If a salutation/prayer/wish is added, or not, don't change it according to your *foobar*. Adding in case of absence is also considered as changing.

*E.g don't change:*

"Prophet" -> Prophet (saww) or Prophet (PBUH)

"Prophet (as)" -> Prophet (May Allah be Pleased with him)

*What's your say on this fellas?*

Answer (score -4):

*"If a salutation/prayer/wish is added, or not, don't change it according to your foobar. **Adding in case of absence is also considered as changing.**"*

I just want to add that addition of PBUH, S.A.W. is not just adding salutation.

> Hazrat Kaab Bin Ujra (R.A.) relates Rasool Allah (PBUH) said, "Come near to the *mimber*." And we Came near to the *mimber*. When He ascended the First step of the *mimber* He said "Aameen". When He ascended the second step of the *mimber* He said, "Aameen". When He ascended the third step He said, "Aameen".
>
> When he decended we said, "O Rasul of Allah, we have heard from You today something which we never heard before".
>
> He said, When I ascended the first step Jibra-eel (A.S.) appeared before me and said, "Woe to him who found the blessed month of Ramadhaan and let it pass without gaining forgiveness", Upon that I said, "Aameen".
>
> When I ascended the second step, he said "Woe to him before whom thy name is mentioned and thendoes not read Durood (salaat alan Nabi) on You". I replied "Aameen".
>
> When I ascended the third step he said, "Woe unto the person in whose presence both parents or one of them attain old age, and (through failure to serve them) is not allowed to enter Jannah" I said "Aameen". *Reported by Haakim*

In *Urdu*, the word "Woe" is translated as *Halakat*. That means death physically and spiritually (no references, native language writer).

Prophet (PBUH) did not prayed *Bad-Duaa* for anyone except in some cases. He even prayered for the people of *Taa-if*. (You may know how they treated him.)

In Islam.SE tags, I suggest, that the namae of Muhammad (S.A.W.) must be with a salutation. Either English or Arabic. If someone does not know or does not want to know then its his own decision. The policy of the site or moderators must be what is the name of site, **Islaam**.

Comment: I want to know your opinion, down voters. It is nice to make someone understand the reason of your opinion

Comment: plz don't bang your head, I'll try to tell you why is this down voted, it is because here in IslamSE although this site is about Islam, here people don't follow the rules of Islam but follow the rules of StackExchange Model. which it takes some time to accommodate with for beginners especially Muslims. Please read the question carefully and only with experience in this site u'll understand why is this downvoted.

Comment: I am okay with your stance. But my part was to convey to MUSLIMS, not anyone else. @servantofWiser

Comment: It seems arguing but I want to restate that I wanted to convey it to Muslims. Doing that, I may have opposed the OP and I can edit the question and add FOR MUSLIMS ONLY. And your point that this site is not for Muslims..Who will visit this site related to Islam..followers of Islam (in majority), isn't it? @servantofWiser

Comment: Oh! dear, I raised a similar issue here [Adding 'non-muslim' tag to questions of non-muslims](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/adding-non-muslim-tag-to-questions-of-non-muslims) that was long before I really understood this platform, Ah! leave it... I would like to ask in a friendly way, why have u stopped participating in IslamSE actively. Maybe you should try to to do that.

Comment: The posts here tend to confuse me. People from different sects tend to persuade others by citing 'their' Ulema and proving others wrong. The quality of questions here is pathetic. This may improve once people start using this website and contribute. Another issue is with voting. People get high votes from people of their own sect, even if the quality of content is low.. So i visit the website whenever i get a notification, otherwise it does not appeal me. @servant-of-Wiser