# Request to reopen a Question

Tags: discussion, moderation

First of all, Please read [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/) by a **Muslima**.

Please reopen the question, as it will benefit the asker, plus a lot of visitor, and our IslamStackExchange will be a reliable source for scholarly guidance.

When a person asks question about `love and relationship` it tends to be verbose. In those cases, rather than closing it as unclear, why not re-word the body and make it clear?

When a desperate person recognizes what he/she is doing and asks for suggestion, we should help him/her. Because that will

1. make us better muslims
2. guide the asker in a right path and prevent him/her from being uninterested in religion.

Answer (score 1):

That question cannot be reopened because there doesn't seem to be *question* in that *post*. It's a *post* asking for [guidance and advice](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/868/3487) which is off-topic since it tends to be opinion-based and doesn't add to the collective knowledge *about* Islam. And [Islam SE: [Is] Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/3487)

This site is strictly *about the subject of Islam* and [is NOT an "Islamic" site!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/116/3487).

The point at which that *post* currently stands, a good question, while editing/rewording in the spirit of [clarify[ing] the meaning of <s>a</s>[the] post without changing it](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), can hardly be done. And it's incumbent on OP to do that, *not the community*.

The burden of asking a good, well-researched and effort driven question is on the asker if they want to get a good and well rounded answer which they could, at their own discretion, use to be a *better muslim* and/or as a *guide* to the *right path* with a caveat of [accept[ing] ... answers at your own risk](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).