# Why no reason is mentioned for deleting question 5428 by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, moderation

This question is deleted by a moderator without mentioning any reason.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/is-ali-explicitly-mentioned-by-name-in-the-quran

What is the reason?

Should a moderator can delete questions without mentioning any reason?

Answer (score 4):

That question was exceedingly low quality, and to my eye looked to serve absolutely no purpose except to [attack Shi'ite beliefs](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22).  [Absolutely no research effort was demonstrated](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/829/22), and no attempt was made to [explain *why* Ali's importance is in any way contingent on his being explicitly mentioned in the Qur'an](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/22).  Almost half of the entire body is [taken up by the greeting](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/22), which if I'd chosen to remove would've left naught but a single-line question.  And even that single-line question [was different on a rather fundamental level](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/5428/revisions) from what the poster originally *asked*.

If it were a recent question, I would've left a comment (as I did for the similarly weak question "[Is “Mahdi” Fact or Fiction? Is he mentioned in the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12252/22)" which follows similar patterns) and given the poster a chance to fix it, or at least learn from their mistake.  In this case, however, the question was more or less abandoned for over a year, and the user who posted it apparently hasn't even logged in since, I didn't feel that leaving *him* a comment explaining my action was necessary.

Given the low quality of the question and the fact that it I felt that it really had no value on this site I chose to delete it.

Comment: it is not attacking shia beliefs. it is only a question about shia. as a shia I do not feel it be any attack to shia. other problems can be solved by some working on it. why only poster improve it? other users can improve it. but it needs a declaration before edit. like this: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/898/what-should-be-done-about-question-10819 when other users know the problem some volunteer come and repair it. anyway it is a very important question that deserves being in this site.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala If you think no-effort-shown questions should be welcome, feel free to argue your point on the meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/829/22

Comment: @goldPseudo, I think it is generally a good mod practice to add a comment whenever a moderator power is used if there is not already one. It will make it clear for other why the action was taken.