# What's up with "3alaykum"?

Tags: discussion, arabic

I've been editing out things like

> assalaamu 3alaykum wa ra7matullahi wa barakaatuh

thinking that they're some mobile phone quirk, and have nothing to do with Arabic or Islam.

I'm wondering numbers like these come about.  In Chinese, we sometimes use numbers to indicate the tone, and I'm wondering if there's something along those lines in Arabic.

**Question**: What's up with "3alaykum"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [Arabic chat alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet). And yes it's a mobile phone quirk :D.

> **3 = ع**

[Shouldn't](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/3487) allow them like them other salutations.

Comment: And 7 = ح to complete your answer.

Comment: (... 9 = ق ....)
(... 2 =  ء ...)
(... 5 = خ ....)
These could also be found in other transliterations.